# How do i get rid of the the extra space when reading from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a word from the file and select one word at random. I can select a random word however some of the words have extra space after the word, e.g an indent. How do i remove this?

```
import random
random_word = []
secret_word = []

def choose_secret_word():
    infile = open("words.txt")
    for every_item in infile:
        random_word.append(every_item)
        secret_word = random.choice(random_word)
    print(secret_word)

choose_secret_word()
```

Comment: If you have duplicate words in the file you will have a greater chance of getting the words with greater frequency. Use a set instead of a list to deduplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `strip()`

Example:

```
print(secret_word.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip)

```
import random
random_word = []
secret_word = []

def choose_secret_word():
    infile = open("words.txt")
    for every_item in infile:
        random_word.append(every_item.strip())
        secret_word = random.choice(random_word)
    print(secret_word)

choose_secret_word()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think applying rstrip() to your word should work : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

So you can do :
    `secret_word = random.choice(random_word).rstrip()`

Answer (score 1):

I would apply a rstrip() method to you code:

```
secret_word.rstrip()
```

More derails here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm
Cheers